# Parsing in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

i have variable `$result` that contains this

```
Country: USA City: NY Latitude: 32.2667 Longitude: 71.9167
```

How do I parse it so I can get the out put like this:

```
Country=USA&City=NY&Latitude=32.2667&Longitude=71.9167
```

Comment: What you describe isn't really parsing but rather string manipulation. Parsing entails extracting structured data from a string.

Comment: It's structured data. It just happens that a quick str replace hack is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack

```
str_replace(array(': ', ' '), array('=', '&'), $string);
```

Comment: i like this one better because it takes care of ': ' before ' ' which prevents ':&'

Comment: @Jayrox, mine too, but I reckon Mario's solution is better because it has only one function call as opposed to mine which has two.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace(' ', '&', str_replace(': ', '=', $string));
```

It may work as you want.

Answer (score 2):

If, at some point you need to do some validation on your data the str_replace method might stop working for you (although it is the easiest way to solve your problem). You would then want to pull the data out in a smarter but more complicated way:

```
$string = "Country: USA City: NY Latitude: 32.2667 Longitude: 71.9167";
$matches = Array();
$has_match = preg_match('/Country: (\w+) City: (\w+) Latitude: ([0-9.]+) Longitude: ([0-9.]+)/',$string,$matches);
if ($has_match) {
    list($country,$city,$lat,$long) = array_slice($matches,1);
}
else {
    print "no matches";
}
```

Now you can do what you like to make sure the $country,$city,$lat and $long values are sane and then join them into a query string with:

```
$query_string = "Country=$country&City=$city&Latitude=$lat&Longitude=$long"
```

Comment: its not working out, my string is stored in the variable like that
    Country: UNITED STATES (US) City: Scottsdale, AZ Latitude: 33.686 Longitude: -111.87

Comment: /Country: (.*) City: (.*) Latitude: ([0-9.]+) Longitude: ([0-9.]+)/
is a more inclusive regex and should work for your data but is less resiliant to bad data.

Comment: change the regex to: /Country: (\w+) (\(.*\)) City: (\w+),(.*) Latitude: ([0-9.]+) Longitude: ([0-9.]+)/

and the match variables to:

list($country,$countrycode,$city,$state,$lat,$long) = array_slice($matches, 1);

to pull the other information out of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expresion in the second answer is ok but it need some small corrections.

preg_match('/^Country=(\w+)&City=(\w+)&Latitude=([0-9.]+)&Longitude=([0-9.]+)/',$string,$matches);